# REGEX_REPLACE in mySQL everything inside character with its value

Tags: mysql, regex, string, sql-update, mariadb

I'd like to replace a text field in mysql using REGEX_REPLACE.

My string looks like this:

```
Hi friends @[Friendly User <user@contoso.com>], what are you doing?
```

What I want is, to remove everything inside the brackets `[]` and except the text inside the `<>`.

So the output should look like this:

```
Hi friends @user@contoso.com, what are you doing?
```

My SQL Code:

```
UPDATE `Chat`
SET `Text` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`Text`, '\<(.*?)\>', 'text inside <>');
```

Link to dbfiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f930852c6bf05fbb31125f42852093f9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `Chat`
SET `Text` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`Text`, '\\[.*\<(.*?)\>.*\\]', '\\1');
```

`\\1` is an escaped `\1` to reference the first capture groups value.  You can use that to reference the captured value in the replacement.  I modified your regex to match the brackets as well.